# Is there any better way to add the dbcontext to a Asp.core MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, constructor, entity-framework-core

In the new MVC Core it seems the standard way to get the context to the controller is by doing this

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public readonly ReportDBContext _db;
    
    public BaseController(ReportDBContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

I can then use

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{   
    public HomeController(ReportDBContext db) : base(db) { }
}
```

To make this a little easier in all other controllers.
Normally in Asp.net MVC I can get a context any time by using `new ReportDBContext()`

Is there a similar way of this now, or do I have to have the context in all controllers in asp.core MVC?

Comment: Seems like you don't understand the benefits of Dependency Injection. DI is incredibly important to writing software that is flexible and easy to maintain. There's really not a good argument to *not* use it. I suggest you watch [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) to obtain an understanding of DI and the benefits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to [@mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62411678/1666800)'s answer, if you decided to use dependency injection, then you can follow the below mentioned steps.

Suppose that you have defined your `ReportDBContext`  like this:

```
public class ReportDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
    //...

    public ReportDBContext(DbContextOptions<ReportDBContext> options) : base(options) 
    { 
      //...
    }
}
```

So you need to config your `startup.cs` like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...What needed
        services.AddDbContext<ReportDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Connection string to your DB"));
        //...What needed
    }
    //...
 }
```

So you can easily inject your `ReportDBContext` to your classes like this(for example inject it to one of your controllers):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ReportDBContext _dbContext;

    public ValuesController(ReportDBContext dbContext )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    //...
}
```

You can simply inject the `ReportDBContext` to your `BaseController` instead of injecting it to every controller in your project too.

**Update 1**

If you do not want to inject the `ReportDBContext` into each constructor, then you can design your `BaseController` as follow by using HttpContext.RequestServices:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected ReportDBContext DbContext => (ReportDBContext)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ReportDBContext));
    //...
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : BaseController
{
    //...

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Sample> Get() => DbContext.Samples.ToList();
}
```

Read more here:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext
2. http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/17ee0ba2-99bb-47f0-ab18-f4fc32f476f8.asp

You will need to install at least these two NuGet packages too:

1. [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.5/)
2. [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/3.1.5) (If the database provider is Microsoft SQL Server)

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I've got now - I just wanted to know if there was a better way of doing it. It just seems like your going to end up with 20 or so controllers each with a contructor that takes the DBContext.

Comment: @RichardHousham I have said at the end of my answer that you can inject your dbContext to your BaseController instead of injecting it to each of the controllers :-)

Comment: Yeah, but that would still require your normal controller to still have it in the constructor ie. public HomeController(ReportDBContext db) : base(db) { }

Comment: Or is there another way?

Comment: @RichardHousham I have updated the answer which now covers your requirements

Comment: Thanks would that follow this DI method or would you refrain doing this yourself?

Comment: @RichardHousham this is not what I do myself, however it follows the DI

Comment: would it cause any issue of request failture  or slow down?

Answer (score 3):

> Normally in Asp.net MVC I can get a context any time by using `new ReportDBContext`()...

You could do the same, i.e. create a new context explicitly in the controller, nowadays. There is nothing that stops for you from doing this, except for best practices.

Some of the benfits of using dependency injection is that you can define the lifetime of the dependency in the `Startup` class and reuse it across all your controllers, and that you can mock away dependencies in your unit tests. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/architectural-principles#dependency-inversion) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) for more information.

But you certainly don't *have to* use dependency injection if you don't want to or have a reason not to do so. The compiler won't force to you define a custom constructor that accepts a dependency.

Comment: This does not always work in all scenarios and may require you to hard code the connection string to the database. It may work fine for running your application, but not when doing a migration. The issue should be fixed in .Net7.

Answer (score 2):

The architecture of ASP.NET Core is built on Dependency Injection. It even has a built-in dependency injection container, but you can also user others like AutoFac or NInject. If you need the DbContext in more than one action, you can use constructor injection, like in your example.

If you need it only once, you can inject it directly into the action method like so:

```
public IActionResult Get([FromServices]ReportDbContext db) 
{ 
   …
}
```

The usage of Dependency Injection makes your code more testable. For your unit tests you could inject a InMemory DbContext.

In my opinion it is even less work than constructing the DbContext yourself. It's done by the framework.

Comment: That's pretty interesting, if I have 2 contexts but maybe only use 1 in a handful of places could I use this then?

Comment: @RichardHousham Yes, that should work. As long as both contexts are registered